# Why does my custom made button sometimes display incorrectly?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, expo

I have a very peculiar and particular problem with a custom made hexagon button in React-Native. I am making these buttons with the technique that is found here at [the shapes of React-Native](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native). my button will sometimes look like this:

[image: Hexagon button with the letter k in the middle and a black line below it.]

Some times the black line is above the letter. The method I am using to make these buttons is a rectangle in the middle and a triangle on the top and bottom. It seems to show a line where the triangles meet the rectangle, but only one triangle or the other and only for one row of the buttons. Here is what the full screen looks like:

[image: full image of the app screen]

Some times it is the middle row only and sometimes it will be the top and bottom rows and the middle will be fine. It appears on both Android and iOS and seems to be related to screen size. I'm just so confused about why it does not happen with every button and only seems to mess up one or two rows. In some cases, depending on the screen size it may be completely fine.

Here is the code for my custom hexagon button:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';


const HexagonButton = props => {
    //Variables for scaling Hex button font.
    let minPortraitWidth = 29.09;//Based on width of 320
    let minLandscapeWidth = 35.5;//Based on width of 568
    let maxPortraitWidth = 93.09;//Based on width of 1024
    let maxLandscapeWidth = 85.375;//Based on width of 1366
    let minFont = 14;
    let maxFont = 35;
    let maxButtonSpace = 16;
    let minButtonSpace = 11;


    let startMinWidth;
    let startMaxWidth;
    let startSpacing;

    if (Dimensions.get('window').width > Dimensions.get('window').height) {
        startSpacing = maxButtonSpace;
        startMinWidth = minLandscapeWidth;
        startMaxWidth = maxLandscapeWidth;
    }
    else {
        startSpacing = minButtonSpace;
        startMinWidth = minPortraitWidth;
        startMaxWidth = maxPortraitWidth;
    }

    const [buttonWidth, setButtonWidth] = useState(Dimensions.get('window').width / startSpacing);
    const [buttonHeight, setButtonHeight] = useState((Dimensions.get('window').width / startSpacing) * 0.60);
    const [minWidth, setMinWidth] = useState(startMinWidth);
    const [maxWidth, setMaxWidth] = useState(startMaxWidth);


    //Handle screen rotate
    useEffect(() => {
        const updateLayout = () => {
            if (Dimensions.get('window').width > Dimensions.get('window').height) {//Landscape Mode
                setMinWidth(minLandscapeWidth);
                setMaxWidth(maxLandscapeWidth);

                setButtonWidth(Dimensions.get('window').width / maxButtonSpace);//Make space for 16 hexagons so we have extra space. 13 buttons per row
                setButtonHeight((Dimensions.get('window').width / maxButtonSpace) * 0.60)// Button height is 60% of button width
            }
            else {//Portrait Mode
                setMinWidth(minPortraitWidth);
                setMaxWidth(maxPortraitWidth);

                setButtonWidth(Dimensions.get('window').width / minButtonSpace);//Make space for 11 hexagons so we have extra space. 9 buttons per row
                setButtonHeight((Dimensions.get('window').width / minButtonSpace) * 0.60)// Button height is 60% of button width
            }


        };

        Dimensions.addEventListener('change', updateLayout);

        return () => {
            Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', updateLayout);
        };
    });


    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
                width: buttonWidth,
                height: buttonHeight
            }}
            accessibilityRole="none"
            >

            <View style={[styles.hexagonBefore, {
                top: -1 * (buttonHeight * 0.45),
                borderLeftWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
                borderRightWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
                borderBottomWidth: buttonHeight * 0.45
            }]} />

            <View style={styles.hexagonInner}>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        fontSize: Math.floor(minFont + (maxFont - minFont) * ((buttonWidth - minWidth) / (maxWidth - minWidth)))//This equation scales my font
                    }}>
                    {props.children}
                </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={[styles.hexagonAfter, {
                bottom: -1 * (buttonHeight * 0.45),
                borderLeftWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
                borderRightWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
                borderTopWidth: buttonHeight * 0.45
            }]} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    hexagonInner: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#ffec33',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    hexagonAfter: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
        borderRightColor: 'transparent',
        borderTopColor: '#ffec33'
    },
    hexagonBefore: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
        borderRightColor: 'transparent',
        borderBottomColor: '#ffec23'
    }
});



export default HexagonButton;
```

and here is the code for the main layout:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import HexButton from './HexagonButton';
import ModeButton from './ModeButton';

const PortraitLayout = props => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <View style={styles.keyboardLayout}>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <HexButton>a</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>b</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>c</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>d</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>e</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>f</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>g</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>h</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>i</HexButton>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <HexButton>j</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>k</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>l</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>m</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>n</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>o</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>p</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>q</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>r</HexButton>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <HexButton>s</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>t</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>u</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>v</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>w</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>x</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>y</HexButton>
                    <HexButton>z</HexButton>
                </View>
            </View>


            <View style={styles.buttonLayout}>
                <ModeButton>
                    Phonics
                </ModeButton>
                <ModeButton>
                    Keyboard
                </ModeButton>
                <ModeButton>
                    Letter
                </ModeButton>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#1e1e19',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    row: {
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginVertical: '5%',
        marginHorizontal: '5%'
    },
    keyboardLayout: {
        height: '50%',
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonLayout: {
        height: '50%',
        width: '100%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    }
});


export default PortraitLayout;
```

I've been working on this for a few days now and it is only frustrating me more. I would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just

```
            borderBottomWidth: buttonHeight * 0.46,
```

in this block

```
<View
        style={[
          styles.hexagonBefore,
          {
            top: -1 * (buttonHeight * 0.45),
            borderLeftWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
            borderRightWidth: buttonWidth * 0.5,
            borderBottomWidth: buttonHeight * 0.46,
          },
        ]}
      />
```

its nice work for me